# How can I get Windows Phone 7 to turn into an RFID Reader?

Tags: windows-phone-7, biztalk, rfid, biztalk-2010

I am currently developing a Windows CE 6.5 application which runs on Unitech's PA690 RFID Reader device, which hosts BizTalk RFID Mobile 2010 to connect with a BizTalk RFID 2010 Server located at the POS.

Here is the URL to the [PA690 RFID device](http://www.ute.com/products_info.php?rbu=5&pc1=50&pc2=83&pid=986):

I now require that the app be ported to Windows Phone 7.

My first obstacle is to convert a Windows Phone 7 to an RFID reader device using some kind of passive bluetooth/NFC enabled adaptor OR use an active RFID reader device that runs the same OS as that in a Windows Phone 7 [The 7 series]

Is there an adaptor/hardware device that can be plugged into Windows Phone 7 to turn it into an RFID reader OR is there an RFID Reader available in the market that runs Windows Phone OS ver. 7.X ?

Comment: This is a hardware question, not a programming question, and is off-topic here. Voting to close for that reason. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has the guidelines about the types of questions that are appropriate to ask here. Please try and stay within them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you cannot do that with the available stock hardware/SDK resources, since:

- There is no publicly supported Bluetooth Channel API
- Windows Phone 7 does not have NFC capabilities.